# Not looping through entire response JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

*Context: working on an Angular2 app with Typescript.*

**Problem:**
I get the following response from an HTTP request.

```
content: [{entryId: 1357, currentAccountId: 893, entryDate: "2005-04-21T17:09:10Z", amount: 7927.5,…},…]
first: true
last: true
number: 0
numberOfElements: 112
size: 2000
sort: [,…]
totalElements: 112
totalPages: 1
```

My goal is to create an array with a part of the entryDate.
This is how I tryed to achieve this:

```
let dataDates = [];
for(let entry of this.data) {
  dataDates.push(entry.entryDate.split('T').shift());
}
```

**This resulted in an Array of 110 items long, 2 less than in the original response.** I thought this was because the last few entries were identical and were overwriting each other. So I tried this:

```
let dataDates = [];
for(let entry of this.data) {
  let obj = { date: entry.entryDate.split('T').shift() };
  let copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
  dataDates.push(copy);
}
```

This resulted in the same Array. A smarter co-worker suggested this:

```
let dataDates: Array<{date: string}> = this.data.map( obj => {
  return { date: obj.entryDate.split( 'T' ).shift() };
} );
```

Also, resulting in the same result.

Why is the for-loop only looping 110 times? While the response clearly states there are 112 items. `console.log(this.data.length)` results in `110` so I think the problem lies there, but I have no idea how to solve this.
Can somebody assist me with this?

**Update 2017-04-05**
I'm doing a similar request to fill a table with the response and I noticed all 112 items were added. The only difference is the size of the response. I only request 20 items at a time to fill the table which has pagination. So I tried requesting smaller sizes since in my use case I could get away with only requesting items with dates from a certain year. Doing this, I was able to circumvent the issue. So to be clear, **the issue remains**, but requesting smaller sizes for some reason returns a correct response.

Comment: It seems that your response just lies to you. The two ways you included for iterating the array seem ok and they should create an array of the same size as the original. Most likely the problem is that the values in `this.data.numberOfElements` and `this.data.totalElements ` is wrong.

Comment: @NitzanTomer but checking the content in my networks tab shows three entries on the same date, april 4th. My new array only has one item with the value of april 4th. This also accounts for the difference of two items.

Comment: If the code you posted is the code you used then there's no reason for what you describe to happen. Add this `console.log(this.data.length)` just before you iterate the array. What does it print?

Comment: you are not getting the proper result from the API need to check the API response.

Comment: Are you parsing the response somewhere? if so, may you share a bit of this code?

Answer (score -1):

What have you done to check the data and make 100% sure you are receiving the data you expect to receive.

Suggestions:

```
  Console.log(this.data);// count the items 
  Console.log(this.data.length);// display the count.
```

- Get the length and run a for loop with an index e.g.,

  for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(i, data[i]);
   }

Comment: Did this already yes to check length of response. In all cases it returned 110, but when I manually counted the length I counted 112.

Comment: Well... do you best to isolate the error. 
So... taking a step back, do you have access to the database?  Are you sure the db table is returning the 112 records with the query you are presenting?